# Como puedo mandar un correo a varios destinatarios? laravel

Tags: laravel

Envió correos de forma normal de la siguiente manera

Controlador:

```
public function Actualizar(Request $request, $numero)
{
    $proyecto= proyectos::find($numero);
$proyecto->id_responsable = $request->input('id_responsable');
$proyecto->id_visit = $request->input('id_visit');
    $proyecto->nombre = $request->input('nombre');
    $proyecto->save();
    echo json_encode($proyecto);
    
    $responsable = DB::table('usuarios')
        ->select('email')
        ->where('id', $proyecto->id_responsable)
        ->get();

    $visit = DB::table('usuarios')
        ->select('email')
        ->where('id', $proyecto->id_visit)
        ->get();

    
    
    Mail::to($responsable)->send( new tareaupdate($proyecto));
    Mail::to($visit)->send( new tareaupdate($proyecto));
}
```

dentro del `->send()` creo una nueva tareaupdate y envió todo lo que me arrojo de $proyecto y lo manda a la vista que es la que se envia para el correo

```
    class tareaupdate extends Mailable
{
    public $msg;
    public $subject  = "Tarea Actualizada";
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($tareas)
 {
        $this->msg = $tareas;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
 public function build()
 {
        return $this->view('emails.tareaupdate');
 }
}
```

mi duda es que quiero enviar a dos destinatarios no a uno solo, ya probé así

```
Mail::to($responsable, $visit)->send( new tareaupdate($proyecto));
```

pero no me permite.

Comment: ¿Y ya intentaste con los métodos [`cc` y `bcc`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail)?

Comment: ya y si lo manda pero como copia a otro destinatario y lo que quiero es agregar otro destinatarios pero no como copia, ya que el cc lo ocupo para mandar el correo de copia al correo del server

Comment: ¿y si agregas un orWhere en la consulta? `$destinatarios = DB::table('usuarios')->select('email')->where('id', $proyecto->id_responsable)->orWhere('id', $proyecto->id_visit) ->get();` luego le pasas la colección al método Mail::to `Mail::to($destinatarios)->send( new tareaupdate($proyecto) );`

Comment: lo probe pero solo me manda un correo al primer correo del primer where, tambien probe el foreach y me manda 2 correos en lugar de 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

```
$destinatario = [ $responsable  , $visit];

Mail::to($destinatario)->send( new tareaupdate($tareas));
```